# How to Remove the Repeated Items Completely from an NSMUtableArray?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

I have an array like:

```
originalArray result: (
     1274,
     1275,
     1276,
     1277,
     1278,
     1279,
     1280,
     1281,
     1282,
     1283,
     1284,
     1285,
     1286,
     1287,
     1288,
     1280,
     1279,
     1283,
     1285,
     1286,
     )
```

But I want to remove the repeated items; finally I want to return the array like:

```
 originalArray result: (
     1274,
     1275,
     1276,
     1277,
     1278,
     1281,
     1282,
     1284,
     1287,
     1288,    
     )
```

Can any one help me on this?

Comment: Do you need to preserve original order?

Answer (score 1):

**NSSet by default will have only unique object. No dublicates allowed.**

```
    //1. Create NSSet from Array
    NSSet *uniqueObjectSet = [NSSet setWithArray:yourArray];

    //2. Make unique array from NSSet
    NSMutableArray *uniqueArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[uniqueObjectSet allObjects]];
```

Comment: I tried with your answer but not working again its giving same respone

Comment: Nothing wrong with this code as long as the objects in the array override `isEqual:` and `hash`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the collection operator @distinctUnionOfObjects to get an array of unique objects:

```
NSArray* filteredNumbers= [numbers valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.intValue"];
```

To get the result that you expect you also have to sort it:

```
filteredNumbers= [filteredNumbers sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
NSArray *copy = [mutableArray copy];
NSInteger index = [copy count] - 1;
    for (id object in [copy reverseObjectEnumerator]) {
       if ([mutableArray indexOfObject:object inRange:NSMakeRange(0, index)] != NSNotFound) {
           [mutableArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
        }
       index--;
    }
```